# wordpress design pattern name

Tags: wordpress, design-patterns, content-management-system, database-schema

Wordpress have a very nifty feature to add custom types: the field post_type in wp_posts. to create a new post type, plugin auothor needs to come up with a new value to put in the field and more tables that links to the wm_post table.

this feature repeats itself in many other cms systems.

My question is: is there a name for this design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

`Content types` seems to be fairly normal with Drupal and other CMSes.

The polymorphism in database in this way could be called [Single Table Inheritance](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html).